# Objective-C add navigationbar to rootview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, xlform

I have simple question with lib XLForms.

https://github.com/mtnbarreto/XLForm

How can I add uinavigationbar into viewcontroller using this forms?

Does anyone have good example?

Here is code from init method of a view

http://pastebin.com/p1q5QQJd

Answer (score 1):

Try This...

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:<Your View Controller>]   
[self.window setRootViewController:navigationController];
```